# Proving with well-ordering principle

Tags: proof-writing

I have this conjecture: Let *a* and *b* be integers and *n* and *m* natural numbers.

$$ a \equiv b \bmod n \Rightarrow a^m \equiv b^m \bmod n$$

I think I got the induction proof, but I'm having difficulties on how to proof this with well-ordering principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be the smallest natural number such that $a^k \not\equiv b^k \mod n$ (such a number exists by the well-ordering principle). We have that $a \equiv b \mod n$ (hence $k \ge 2$). If now $a^{k-1} \equiv b^{k-1} \mod n$, then

$$
a^k \equiv a^{k-1} a \equiv b^{k-1} a \equiv b^{k-1} b \equiv b^k \mod n,
$$

which contradicts $a^k \not\equiv b^k \mod n$. Hence, $a^{k-1} \not\equiv b^{k-1} \mod n$, and thus $j:=k-1$ is a smaller number with $a^j \not\equiv b^j \mod n$, and since $k \ge 2$, $j$ is a natural number. This contradicts the fact that $k$ was the smallest number with that property.

EDIT: By 'natural number' i mean positive integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still having a little trouble understanding your answer, especially the middle statement.

Comment: The middle statement follows from the following theorem: If $a \equiv a' \mod n$ and $b \equiv b' \mod n$, then $ab \equiv a'b' \mod n$.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Hm, sorry that wasn't in one of our lists of propositions for modulo.

Comment: This is proven as follows: If $a \equiv a' \mod n$, then by definition $n|(a - a')$. Analogously, $n|(b - b')$. Since $ab - a'b' = (a - a')b' + (b - b')a$, $n|(ab - a'b')$, and by definition $ab \equiv a'b' \mod n$.

Comment: @dendritic: As the above is one of the most fundamental theorems for modulo, it would be rewarding to learn it. (Sometimes the theorem is also called 'well-definedness of products modulo a natural number'.)

Comment: Our professor accidentally duplicated one of the propositions in our list, so that duplicated one must have supposed to be the one you showed me now. But he never told us what the duplicated was supposed to be.

Comment: There is also a theorem which is the exact same version for addition (if $a \equiv a' \mod n$ and $b \equiv b' \mod n$, then $a + b \equiv a' + b' \mod n$). If you have had this theorem, it is possible that you've had the other one too.

Comment: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kwhyte/math215/Worksheet215.pdf

Comment: In any case, by knowing these two you are going to impress everybody. Just sayin.

Comment: Looks like you can use 0.17 instead!

Comment: OK, for the first $\equiv$ sign and the last you need 0.13 and to know that for every $c \in \mathbb R$, $c c^{k-1} = c^k$.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$a^m-b^m=(a-b)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}a^{m-k-1}b^{k}=(a-b)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+\ldots+ab^{m-2}+b^{m-1})$

So

$a-b | a^m-b^m $

Comment: How is the well-ordering principle used here?

Comment: It's a nice and valuable answer, but it misses just a slight bit in the question.